# How can I create a component into node for diagram deployment

Tags: uml, modelio

I started with Modelio for the design of computer systems.
My problem is at deployment diagram
I create my node diagram. but I'm blocked here

eg I have a node "server application"
I like to mention that tomcat is a component for this node. but I can not. What I do know that I mention here as Information Item.
Haw can crate component into node server application here .than you all
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you have any question dedicated to Modelio the best would to post it on [their forum](http://www.modelio.org/forum/index.html) ...

Now concerning your question and according to UML2.4.1 specification, instead of using component I would use the concept of DeployedArtifact (section 10.3.3 of the sepcification) which is " an artifact or artifact instance that has been deployed to a deployment target".

Hoping it helps ...

RB